# Check if there is an Object3D at specific distance from another Object3D in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I would like to check whether there is an Object3D at a specific distance from another Object3D in three.js. I do not know what object the second one is, only the first one, so using distanceTo(obj: Object3D) does not work. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
var obj = _Object3D_;
var objs = [ _array_of_Object3D_ ];

for ( i = 0; i < objs.length; i++ ){
  var d = obj.position.distanceTo(objs[i].position);

  if (d < desiredDistanceValue) {
    // Do desired stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't quite what I meant. Updated the question to hopefully be more clear.

Comment: Wouldn't this be rather slow with a lot of meshes? Is there any other method? I'm thinking raycasting, but I'm not entirely sure how I would achieve this with the Raycaster class.

Comment: This is the simplest method. Surely, the more meshes you have, the more performance drop you get with it. Three.js doesn't have a method you described out-of-box, so you have to implement it yourself. Creativity is up to you :)